# Graphics class: How to create a margin at the top,left,right and bottom of the image

Tags: c#

on Image Magick, we can create a margin at the top, left, right and bottom of the image using -splice option and -gravity option.

I want to create a margin at the top, left, right and bottom of the image **using C# Graphics class.**

But I don't know how to create a margin using C# class, enable to create a margin using C# class.

So, I want to know the above mentioned.

Comment: What have you tried so far? If you show us your code, and where you're having difficulty, then we can help.

Comment: Maybe you should consider using [Magick.NET](https://magick.codeplex.com), its a C# wrapper for ImageMagick.

Answer (score 4):

You don't want to create a margin on a C# graphics class.

A Graphics object is an abstraction of "something capable of being drawn upon". It can be the screen, a printer, or a bitmap.

You can't resize a bitmap. You have to create a new one, and copy the existing one onto it.

So what you need to do is create a new bitmap, which is a copy of the existing bitmap, but with a margin around, then use a Graphics object to copy the bitmap onto it.

So you need to

- create a bitmap which is large enough to have the bitmap and the margin around. Use the Width and Height properties to find out the size of the existing bitmap.
- Create a Graphics object which allows you to draw on the bitmap (Check the constructor overloads)
- Then use the graphics object to copy the old bitmap into the new bitmap. (Check out the DrawImage method)
- Finally dispose the graphics object, and save the bitmap in the desired format.

Answer (score 1):

Usually you are defining the margin in the properies of the System.Windows.Forms.Control/Form instance itself. See the designer of VisualStudio. And - if you need to paint your control yourself in it's OnPaint method or Paint event, you can try one of the following.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        static readonly Bitmap image = Properties.Resources.gecco_quad_dunkel;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            // using my own margin
            const int margin = 20;

            var dest = new Rectangle(
                e.ClipRectangle.X + margin, 
                e.ClipRectangle.Y + margin, 
                e.ClipRectangle.Width - 2 * margin, 
                e.ClipRectangle.Height - 2 * margin
                );

            e.Graphics.DrawImage(image, dest);
        }

        private void panel2_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            // using the margin information of the System.Windows.Forms.Control/Form

            var co = (Control)sender;
            var dest = new Rectangle(
                e.ClipRectangle.X + co.Margin.Left, 
                e.ClipRectangle.Y + co.Margin.Top, 
                e.ClipRectangle.Width - co.Margin.Left - co.Margin.Right, 
                e.ClipRectangle.Height - co.Margin.Top - co.Margin.Bottom
                );

            e.Graphics.DrawImage(image, dest);
        }
    }
}
```

In my form I added two containers (Panel) in green and orange. The orange one has a margin of 20px on all sides.
[image]